# how to add simple func to a button in openerp 7

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, odoo

I have created a module in my openerp 7 . I have made a simple button but unable to declare functions to this button . I dont know the syntax because I am facing xml issues when creating the logic . I am lacking in syntax .

Plz help

Answer (score 7):

In openerp you can create 3 types of buttons

1. button with `type='workflow'`: This is the default type if you don't specify any type. If you have created a workflow for your model and you want to change the functionality of the button depending on the state/status, then you can use type='workflow'. You can find example in sale order
2. button with `type='object'`: If you want to call a specific function defined in your model, then use type='object'. For example, let 'my.test.model' is your model and you have created.

   ```
   def my_test(self,cr, uid, ids, context=none):
       #your code comes here
       return True
   ```

   in your xml file add the button, for example `<button name="my_test" string="MY test function" type="object"/>`
3. Button with `type='action'`: If you want to open an action, for example open a wizard, then use this type of buttons. Here in xml provide the name of the button as id of the action you want to open

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 'my_field': fields.function(_get_myfield, method=True, string='Reference', type='char'),
def _get_myfield(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
         #your logic declared here
    return result
```

Comment: What changes to be made in xml ? And can u give me some hint about syntax inside the func . I want to declare fields through my button